# Different execution behaviour between Wolframcloud and Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: syntax, wolfram-cloud

When I execute in Wolfram Mathematica:

```
s=0.3;
m=5;
x=6;
```

it works. But when I execute the same on wolframcloud.com it returns `Syntax: Incomplete expression; more input is needed.`

[image]

Is this normal? Does wolframcloud have different syntax?

*Update:*  The cell expression is the following:

```
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{"s","=","0.3"}],";"}],"\[IndentingNewLine]",
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{"m","=","5"}],";"}]}],"\n",
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{"x","=","6"}],";"}]}],"Input",
  CellLabel -> "In[28]:= "]
```

*Update:* I tried using "\n" or "[IndentingNewLine]" in both cases but cloud still returned an error.

Essentially, this is what Cloud accepts (and it doesn't matter if I use "[IndentingNewLine]" instead of "\n"):

```
Cell[BoxData[{
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"s","=","0.3"}],";"}],"\n",
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"m","=","5"}],";"}],"\n",
 RowBox[{
  RowBox[{"x","=","6"}],";"}]}],"Input",
CellLabel -> "In[34]:= "]
```

So the problem is the extra RowBox[{}] which I have no clew how it ended up like that. Maybe I had deleted something before that. But I guess this suggests that Mathematica failed to evaluate correctly the validity of the expression.

*Update:* I also realised that pasting the same text inside Cloud and Mathematica, is not being converted into the same cell expression. For example pasting the line:

```
Solve[{PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], x] == y, sigma > 0}, x, Reals]
```

for me works on Cloud but not on Mathematica 10.2. Which either suggests a bug, or different syntax.

Comment: The code works on Wolfram Cloud for me.  Do you have an invisible character that you accidentally typed?

Comment: I updated with an image of what I see.

Comment: Use `Show Cell Expression` to see what the cell looks like. If you don't know the shortcut, you can go to the settings icon that appears next to the cell bracket, and then select `Advanced | Show Cell Expression`. If it's not obvious what the problem is, you can edit the contents into your question.

Comment: From your responses, I get the feeling that Wolfram embeds formatting on the strings. Can I disable this and always have my mind peaceful that what I see is what I run? Or is there any important reason behind this action?

Comment: Your cell expression works for me in the cloud and on the desktop.  No difference. -- I'm not sure how to answer your last comment. It is necessary for your input to be parsed as it is typed.  This is managed by translating it into the "box form" you see in the cell expression.  There's no way to turn it off.

Comment: I think it's the `\[IndentingNewLine]` character that is the problem. How did you enter the code into the cloud? Actually, I think it's using a mixture of `\n` and `\[IndentingNewLine]` that is the issue. Just using one or the other has no issues.

Comment: Can you try to evaluate the updated expression on both cloud and Mathematica to confirm that it works?

Comment: I think the syntax error issue is a bug and worth reporting to Wolfram support.